# swift: Importing CSwiftV Framework

Tags: swift, csv, import, frameworks

After reading countless articles on importing the CSwiftV framework, I am still getting the error 'No such module' when trying to do the statement

```
import CSwiftV
```

Here are the steps I took:

1. Download CSwiftV-master from GitHub
2. Drag the xcodeproject into my project folder

[image]

3. Under my project settings, adding the CSwiftVOSX and CSwiftVIOS frameworks to the Target Dependencies and Linked Libraries:

[image]

In the tutorials I read, the import statement should be working right now.  This has taken me hours and is really becoming frustrating.  Can anybody lend some wisdom?

Thanks in advance
Colin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import it as a pod. Open up your terminal application and navigate to your project folder. If you do not know how to do this just type `cd` and then drag your project folder on to your terminal window. This will give the path to the file hit `enter` Now type `pod init` This creates a Podfile for you. You can edit it in terminal or in what ever text editor your Choice. Make your podfile look like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
xcodeproj '[YOURPROJECT].xcodeproj'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target '[*YourApp*]' do
  pod 'CSwiftV'
end
```

`Save` then back to terminal. type `pod install` hit enter. This will install the pod. Close your project in Xcode and open the YOURPROJECT.workspace. `Clean` your project and then `Run` and all should be well.

Let me know if there is anything else you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried doing what you suggested but still no luck.  Just to clarify, when you say 'drag the project files in', which files do you mean exactly?  I tried adding CSwiftV.swift into my project but that wouldn't work either.

Comment: I just tried it I could not get it to work but adding it as a pod does. Let me edit my answer with the instructions.

Comment: You can do this with anything that has a pod set up and you don't have to pull in any files into your project. Welcome to cocapods

Comment: You should also delete the CSwiftV.project from yours no need to keep it in there.

Comment: OK so I had to update my ruby version and my cocoapods version.  I was able to create a podfile in my project directory and populated it how you said.  Except now when I enter 'pod install' i get this :

Colin-McParlands-MacBook-Pro:Mobile_A3 Colini$ pod install
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
`[!] The dependency CSwiftV is not used in any concrete target.`

`[!] xcodeproj was renamed to project. Please use that from now on.`

Comment: Ya so it will automatically create a workspace for you. So close your project and open the [YourProject].xcworkspace.

Comment: I am also assuming that you changed the YOURPROJECT to the actual name of your project.

Comment: I edited what should be in your podfile. Change that and pod install again.

Comment: Ok awesome so the pod is installed and everything and there is a new workspace file there.  I open the workspace file and the 'Pods' are listed under my project.  Thing is I'm still getting the error on the import statement...Is this statement no longer necessary?

Comment: It is still necessary I would delete it, run your project, then add it back in and run again.

Comment: That did it!!!  Thank you SO much @Daniel !!!  I appreciate all your time.  Best wishes